# How decode strings contained in Adobe InDesign files?

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is a font name: `"中arial"`

I am using StreamReader to read my file:

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(parm_strFileName)
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
   Dim     strFontName = objReader.ReadLine()
Loop
```

Value return is `&lt;4E2D&gt;arial`

How can I convert `&lt;4E2D&gt;arial` to `"中arial"`?

More :

if my text =`"トの通りに置換test"` 
it will encode is

```
"<stFnt:fontFamily>&lt;30C8&gt;&lt;306E&gt;&lt;901A&gt;&lt;3‌​08A&gt;&lt;306B&gt;&‌​lt;7F6E&gt;&lt;63DB&‌​gt;test</stFnt:fontF‌​amily>"
```

Comment: How are you encoding that string? it seems a mix of urlencoding and utf8...

Comment: This is a file data of Adobe Indesign, It auto encode .

Comment: Dim str=ChrW("&H4E2D") , it will return str= "中"

Comment: @DT: Looks like you already have your answer: Extract the numerical values between `&lt;` and `&gt;` and convert them with `ChrW`. `Regex.Replace` with a custom `MatchEvaluator` sounds like a good fit for this.

Comment: If convert each character, i think Chrw can .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
       parm_strFont ="&lt;30C8&gt;&lt;306E&gt;&lt;901A&gt;&lt;3‌​08A&gt;&lt;306B&gt;&‌​lt;7F6E&gt;&lt;63DB&‌​gt;test"
parm_strFont = Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(parm_strFont )
        Dim rgx As New Regex("<[0-9a-zA-Z]+>")
        For Each m As Match In rgx.Matches(parm_strFont)
            Dim strvalue = m.Value
            strvalue = strvalue.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "")
            Dim str = ChrW("&H" & strvalue)
            parm_strFont = parm_strFont.Replace(m.Value, str)
        Next
```

Comment: I've tried that code and it doesn't work for me. Your original string has some "non-printable" control characters, so for this to work i had to add `parm_strFont = Regex.Replace(parm_strFont, "\p{C}+", "")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following overload of the System.IO.StreamReader constructor. Assuming the content is UTF-8, you can do:

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(parm_strFileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: it can't read, in my file data is   <stFnt:fontFamily>&lt;4E2D&gt;arial</stFnt:fontFamily>

Comment: if my text ="トの通りに置換test" , it will endcode is "<stFnt:fontFamily>&lt;30C8&gt;&lt;306E&gt;&lt;901A&gt;&lt;308A&gt;&lt;306B&gt;&lt;7F6E&gt;&lt;63DB&gt;test</stFnt:fontFamily>", how can convert again.